# Venda no ThemeForest

Tags: html5, css3, wordpress-theme

Fala galera,

alguém daqui do Brasil já vendeu itens no ThemeForest? Compensa? Tem outros marketplaces alternativos? Eu vi que precisa de documentação do item pra vender no ThemeForest, alguém teria exemplo? Enfim, qualquer dica é válida.

Abraço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fui vendedor na marketplace themeforest durante 2 meses, vendi muito meu template e o tirei do ar no terceiro mês, vale muito a pena porem prepare-se para o suporte. Muitos usuários compras e querem suporte completo desde um pequeno detalhe a algo que você não adicionou em seu produto.

Os valores você pode ver [neste link](http://themeforest.net/make_money/become_an_author).

Dicas preciosas:

1. Documentação completa, explique tudo sobre o produto;
2. Qualidade do código, quanto mais fácil for, mais fácil será de manter;
3. Divulgue nas redes sociais, seus clientes estão nas redes sociais;
4. De preferencia para templates Wordpress (são os mais vendidos);
5. Tenha paciência, muitos clientes não sabem nada.

Lhe desejo boa sorte em suas vendas, eu quero em breve voltar a vender na rede. Só me falta tempo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, e tipo a documentação seria coisas como (no caso de ser o html), muda a cor do topo, mudar a fonte, duplicar pagina essas coisas?

Comment: Primeiro comece explicando a arquitetura do seu projeto, fale sobre os diretórios, tecnologias usadas e o que é preciso ser instalado. Depois mostre exemplos. Uma dica importante é comprar um template muito bem vendido da mesma categoria do seu e ver a documentação dele.

Comment: Existe algum passo a passo de como vender um produto por lá Bruno ?

Comment: De uma olhada https://help.author.envato.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000471943-A-step-by-step-guide-to-the-upload-process